# Почему «ночлег», а не «ночьлег»?

Tags: орфография

Можете сказать: во-первых, почему в слове *ночлег* нет *ь*? во-вторых, почему мы пишем *оранжевый*, *лучший*, *худший* без таки *ь* тоже-с? А почему же-с в слове *меньший* он есть-таки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это тема: Мягкий знак для обозначения **мягкости** согласных.

1. Но**ч**лег, лу**ч**ший. Не обозначается мягкость всегда мягкого звука Ч.
2. Ора**нж**евый,  ху**дш**ий. Перед шипящими Ж и Ш находятся твердые гласные Н и Д, поэтому нет мягкого знака.
3. Ме**ньш**ий. Обозначаются мягкость звука Н. Сравнить (твердый звук Н): тра**нш**ея.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148848/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 1):

мягкий знак на конце существительного после шипящего нужен для обозначения рода, а не для какой-то фонетики.

Камыш - мужской род.

ночь, мышь - женский род.

мышка - окончание а, поэтому мягкий знак в середине слова не нужен.

меньше - ь очевидно не после шипящей, а после н.

Comment: У мягкого знака три функции1) Мягкий знак для обозначения мягкости согласных: тень, деньки, горький
(2) Грамматический мягкий знак на конце слова после шипящих (речь, вещь, но: луч, плащ).
(3) Разделительный мягкий знак, обозначающий звук Й (вьётся, но: въехал).

Comment: Выбор знака в середине слова регулируется специальными правилами, при этом для шипящих есть своя тема. Мягкий знак (обозначение мягкости) пишется по своим правилам. И не надо его писать, если звук твердый. Тема кажется простой, потому что выучена на  автомате, без понимания смысла того, что и почему человек пишет. Это ясно видно из комментариев и ответов.  Просто на практике достаточно этого АВТОМАТИЧЕСКОГО письма.  Но для развития интеллекта понимать тему очень даже неплохо.